My java program not responding to key press/release
I have a program that detects mouse movements and draws line according to the path of the mouse pointer tip when the mouse is dragged. NEXT I tried to make the program detect key events, the code being in a separate (sub) class(named Z_keyDetection) inside the main class. The mouse part works fine but the keyboard events are not being detected. Cannot figure out what I did wrong. I am a beginner in Java. Can any one help please? My program is shown below:
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.*;    
import java.awt.event.*;    

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Z_MouseDraggedTest {
JFrame frame ;
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    new Z_MouseDraggedTest();
}

public Z_MouseDraggedTest() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) {
            }
         
            frame = new JFrame("Handwriting");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(new TestPane()));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
 
public class Z_keyDetection extends JFrame{
  public void Z_keyDetection(String[] argv) throws Exception {
//JFrame myJFrame = new JFrame();

frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
      System.out.println("Up Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
      System.out.println("Down Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
      System.out.println("Left Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
    System.out.println("Right Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
    }
  }
});

//myJFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}                           
                          
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Map<Point, List<Point>> mapPoints;
    private Point currentPoint;

    public TestPane() {
        mapPoints = new HashMap<>(2) ;  //25);
        MouseAdapter mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                currentPoint = e.getPoint();
                mapPoints.put(currentPoint, new ArrayList<Point>(25));
            }
           
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                List<Point> points = mapPoints.get(currentPoint);
                if (points.isEmpty()) {
                    mapPoints.remove(currentPoint);
                }
                currentPoint = null;
            }
              
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                List<Point> points = mapPoints.get(currentPoint);
                points.add(me.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }
        };
        addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseListener);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 800);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Point startPoint : mapPoints.keySet()) {
            List<Point> points = mapPoints.get(startPoint);
            for (Point p : points) {
                if (startPoint != null) {
                    g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, p.x, p.y);
                }
                startPoint = p;
            }
        }
    }
}

}
I do not know why key detection is not working in my program, although I tried including the code block below, which, as a standalone, compiles and runs as expected(detecting key events). The modification of this code block below before including in my above program are to change

"public static void main" TO "public static void Z_keyDetection".

"myJFrame" TO frame
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Z_keyDetection {
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
JFrame myJFrame = new JFrame();
myJFrame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
System.out.println("Up Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
}
else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
System.out.println("Down Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
}
else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
System.out.println("Left Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
}
else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
System.out.println("Right Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
}
}
);
myJFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}


